# Llamada a la función indefinida imagettftext ()

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quiero insertar texto a una imagen `jpg`
con `php`,estoy utilizando `imagestring()` y todo sale bien, pero no me permite cambiar el tipo de letra, entonces utilizo la función `imagettftext()` pero cuando hago uso de esta, me sale el siguiente error:

**ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO QUE TENGO:**

```
$im = imagecreate ( 400 , 400 ); 
$fondo = imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);
$negro = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);
$texto = "Prueba";
$fuente = "arial.ttf";
$font_zise=33;

$img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg("../../img/nombreImagen.jpg");

imagettftext($img2,4,0,197,40,$negro,$fuente,$texto);
// imagestring($img2,4,197,40,$texto,$negro);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 

imagejpeg($img2);

imagedestroy($img2);
```

Tengo entendido que debo tener instalada la librería **GD** y **FreeType** para que ejecute el `phpinfo()`. Según la información que veo, tengo instalado el **GD**, pero el **FreeType** no, como podría instalarlo?

Comment: ¿Dónde está la función `imagettftext`? No se ve en el código, ¿existe en ese ámbito?

Comment: la funcion imagettftext() esta en el codigo esta abajo de la linea donde creo la imagen $img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg("../../img/nombreImagen.jpg");

Comment: No, eso no es la función, eso sería **una llamada a la función**. La función debe ser algo así: **`function imagettftext($img,$num1,$num2,$num3,$num4,$color,$fuente,$texto) { //y aquí todo el código de la función }`** ¿me entiendes lo que quiero decir?

Comment: si entiendo, pero entonces la funcion imagettftext() como se hace o que codigo lleva? estoy confundido

Comment: Si para usar esta función hace falta FreeType y no lo tienes instalado ¿la pregunta no sería cómo instalar FreeType? y para eso hace falta información ¿es localhost? ¿trabajas con linux?¿mac? etc..

Comment: Yo no te puedo decir el código que lleva esa función, debe llevar el código que haga lo que quieres hacer al llamarla. Eso no lo puede saber nadie más que tú. Imaginemos una función que debe sumar dos números. La misma se escribe así: `function sumar($a, $b) { $suma=$a+$b; echo "La suma de $a + $b  es igual a $suma"; }`  Ahora, para llamarla, haces esto: `sumar (3,8);` y te imprimirá la suma de `3` y de `8`.

Comment: estoy trabajando en local y estoy utilizando mac

Answer (score 0):

Quiza no esta definido bien tu path a la fuente ejemplo:

**incluyendo la fuente**

```
<?php
// Establecer la variable de entorno para GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

// Nombrar la fuente que va ser usada (observe la ausencia de la extensión .ttf)
$fuente = 'UnaFuente';
?>
```

**ejemplo completo:**

```
<?php
// Establecer el tipo de contenido
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Crear la imagen
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Crear algunos colores
$blanco = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$gris = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$negro = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $blanco);

// El texto a dibujar
$texto = 'Testing...';
// Reemplace la ruta por la de su propia fuente
$fuente = 'arial.ttf';

// Añadir algo de sombra al texto
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $gris, $fuente, $texto);

// Añadir el texto
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $negro, $fuente, $texto);

// Usar imagepng() resultará en un texto más claro comparado con imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

**RESULTADO:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tambien puedes usar una libreria muy buena :[gd-text](https://github.com/stil/gd-text)